# Centralise imports. Pycharm underlines my objects

Tags: python, import, pycharm

I have a `main.py` file which contains imports from the standard library, as well as my own modules. I invoke this from the command line as well as through Pycharm.

I also have a Scientific View file "interactive.py" which references `main.py`. I can run code blocks separately (labelled as `#%%`). As follows:

#### main.py:

```
import sys
from MyMod import MyFunc
```

#### interactive.py:

```
import main as m

#%%
m.MyFunc <-- recognised
m.sys <-- recognised
sys <-- not recognised
```

Pycharm recognises `m.MyFunc` but not `sys`. I want to leverage Pycharm's code completion/documentation on all my programmatic imports in an idiomatic way (I don't like writing `m.sys`)

Any ideas

Comment: that's because `sys` is not a name in scope. you *could* use a starred import, I suppose.

Comment: There are many imports. I want to keep it DRY